Dimensionality of Tensor Product in Bimodules with Distinct Actions
Failing Example Show
Consider $Z=(Z\setminus\{0\}, \cdot, [1])$ as the multiplicative monoid of integers, denoted by elements $[1], [2], \dots$, etc. Denote the free $\mathbb{Z}$-ring $\mathbb{Z}[Z]$ by $F$. Elements of $F$ are in the form $\sum_{[p]\in Z} a_p [p]$, where $a_p \in \mathbb{Z}$.

For $a_p [p]$ and $b_q [q] \in F$, the left action is given by
$$a_p [p] * b_q [q] = a_p b_q [pq]$$
For $c_r [r]$ and $b_q [q] \in F$, the right action is given by
$$b_q [q] \times c_r [r] = \underbrace{b_q[q] + \cdots + b_q[q]}_{c_r \text{ times}} = b_q c_r[q],$$
where $[r]$ is unused.

Since these two actions are compatible
$$
(a_p [p] * b_q [q]) \times c_r [r] =
(a_p b_q [pq])  \times c_r [r] = 
a_p b_q c_r [pq] =
a_p [p] * (b_q [q] \times c_r [r]),
$$
(note that the last equation holds for any $[x] \in Z$,
$a_p b_q c_r [pq] = a_p [p] * (b_q [q] \times c_r [x]),$
we can view $F$ as a $(F, F)$-bimodule over itself. Therefore, $F\otimes_F F$ yields
\begin{equation}a_p [p] \otimes b_q [q] \stackrel{(1)}{=} 1 [p] \times a_p [x] \otimes b_q [q] = 1 [p] \otimes a_p [x] * b_q [q] = [p] \otimes a_p b_q[xq], \text{ for all } x \in \mathbb{Z} \end{equation}
Questions

Is there a way to "enforce" the last equation's initial equality (1) such that $[x]:=[a_p]$, ensuring that in each coset $a_p [p] \otimes b_q [q]$ there is exactly one $[p] \otimes a_pb_q[a_pb_q]$ or equivalently non of $1[p] \otimes a_pb_q[yb_q]$ such that $ y \neq a_p$?

More generally, is there a ring $R$ so that there exists an $(R,R)$-bimodule $M$, whose right $R$-action includes the standard $\mathbb{Z}$-action and its left action is distinct; such that $M\otimes M$ has dimension $\dim(M) + \dim(M)$?

Considering alternative structures: Should I instead consider tensoring more complicated structures then modules?


Motivation
My motivation is to construct modules $N^{(t)}$ generated by $[p_t]\otimes [p_{t-1}]\otimes \cdots\otimes [p_1]$, where $N^{(0)}=R$ and $N^{(t+1)} = N\otimes_R N^{(t)}$. Furthermore,  we desire to have inclusion $i:N^{(t)}\to N^{(t+1)}$ such that if $w = a\times [1]\otimes [p_{t-1}]\otimes \cdots\otimes [p_1] \in N^{(t)}$ (a sum of $a$ elements), then $$i(w) = [1] \otimes [a]\otimes [p_{t-1}]\otimes \cdots\otimes [p_1] \in N^{(t+1)}.$$

The "right action" is not really a module action, since the unity element does not act as the identity. Also be careful, $\mathbb{Z}\setminus \{0\}$ is not a group but a monoid (this is not really important for the rest).
But most importantly, your formula $(a_p [p] * b_q [q]) \times c_r [r] = a_p [p] * (b_q [q] \times c_r [r])$ is incorrect, since according to your definition
$$(a_p [p] * b_q [q]) \times c_r [r] = a_pb_qc_r[r]$$
and
$$ a_p [p] * (b_q [q] \times c_r [r]) = a_pb_qc_r[pr].$$
So I don't know if you're interested in the rest of your question given that your premises do not hold?

Thanks so much for answering! I have updated the definition of the right action, so the formula should now work. I would be indeed interested in any other insight into my questions.
